# Press Release for letting people know we have gone live

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I would like to invite cycling advocacy groups such as the UK's venerable CTC to join us on bicycles.se.

To do so would be a lot easier if we had a standard article in press release format that we could just email out. Then the likes of the CTC could simply post the press release to their news blog (as well as read it themselves).

If we do what other people wanting PR do, i.e. a Press Release then it makes it easy for recipients to simply cut and paste from it to get their own article together. We have to make it easy for them this way or else we won't be competing properly for their attention.

Comment: Have a look here: [One short paragraph that describes the site](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/416/one-short-paragraph-that-describes-this-site). It's actually longer than one paragraph, you could probably use this text as a basis for a press release.

Comment: I will update that thread. I think we need the surrounding structure, e.g.: http://www.foe.co.uk/resource/how_tos/cyw_64_press_release.pdf

Comment: A press release is something quite different than a blurb for a flyer or a web FAQ, I think having a PR is a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps part of the problem here is that people don't know what the difference would be between this and the *one short paragraph* thread. Where would this be used that it wouldn't? Knowing that might help people answer this.